# Редактирование изображений в NSTextView по размеру и расположению в тексете

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, drag-n-drop

Приветствую. У меня Есть необходимость создать текст перетаскиванием мышкой в окно NSTextView собственно текста и картинок. Это позволяет сам NSTextView по умолчанию при включении  AllowsImportGraphics. 
Вопрос в том, как редактировать изображения по размеру. 
В документации есть упоминание NSTextAttachmentCell. Но как к нему стучаться. И где искать непонятно.

Буду признателен за наводку и подсказку.

Comment: чет не нашел, это в какой sdk?

Comment: Стандартный. Cocoa при установке свойств  .... Позволяет вставить рисунок в textView а вот как его тут же отформатировать по размеру и расположению я не знаю. 
В чем собственно и вопрос